# Why can I not convert Foo<T?> to Foo<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic Struct "FileProperty" which consists of an int 'offset' and a T 'value'.
If I do something like the following..:

```cs
FileProperty<long?> fp1 = new FileProperty(value: null, offset: 0);
fp1.value = 1;
```

..neither of the following work:

```cs
FileProperty<long> fp2;
fp2 = fp1;                       // Cannot implicitly convert type 'Database.FileProperty<long>' to 'Database.FileProperty<long?>'
fp2 = (FileProperty<long>) fp1;  // Cannot convert type 'Database.FileProperty<long>' to 'Database.FileProperty<long?>'
```

Even if I write an explicit conversion I just get:
*'User-defined operator cannot convert a type to itself'*
which makes sense but doesn't help me.

The issue I am having is that I **know** *'T? != null'* but I can't convert Foo<T?> to Foo.

Comment: If you are considering that the `?` for nullable value types in C# is just syntactic sugar, a short-hand for `Nullable<TValue>`, then you will understand that `long` is not the same type as `Nullable<long>`. And therefore, `FileProperty<Nullable<long>>` (_FileProperty<long?>_) is not the same type nor derived from `FileProperty<long>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due the difference between `Foo<Nullable<T>>` and `Foo<T>`. These are very different types, and in the name of strict typing a cast is blocked because it needs to know that the nullability will be dealt with upfront

One way to properly handle this cast is to use the null coalescing operator to check if its null, and if so provide the fallback value for it

In this snippet I chose to use the [default operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default). Since `FileProperty` is a struct, it will default to a struct where `value` is null and `offset` is 0. If this is undesirable, swap it out to fit your needs

```cs
FileProperty<long?> fp1 = new FileProperty(value: 1, offset: 0);

FileProperty<long> fp2 = fp1 ?? default(FileProperty<long>);
```

You may also just want to throw an exception if its null

```cs
FileProperty<long> fp2;
if (fp1 != null) fp2 = fp1;
else throw new Exception("No");
```

Comment: You could also make use of a [throw expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#the-throw-expression) to handle the situation where `fp1` is null: `FileProperty<long> fp2 = fp1 ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(fp1)} cannot be null.");`